# Запись данных из файла в коллекцию List,ArrayList

Tags: java, коллекции

Как записать данные из файла в коллекцию List или ArrayList?Есть файл(рис.1),нужно построчно записать его в коллекцию.Помогите,пожалуйста
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```
List <String> result = Files.lines(Paths.get("Main.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).collect(Collectors.toList());
```